# Foil Wrapping BBQ Ribs in Convection?

Tags: baking, ribs, convection

Can you wrap spare ribs in foil and convection bake or should it be conventional baking when wrapped in foil?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real functional difference. Only change between the two types of ovens is a fan blowing the hot air around...however...if aluminum gets too hot it was melt so don't let it touch any metal if you are baking over 385.

Comment: 385F or 385C? Aluminum's melting point is 1221F/660C, though - is this about keeping it from touching the elements, which will be much hotter than the oven temperature? Or can foil really melt that much below aluminum's melting point?